# Multi core machine - cpu load metric

Tags: perl, unix, operating-system, cpu-usage, multicore

In a multi core machine what is the best metric to understand whether cpu is loaded or not ?

I have a web application that sends a post request to apache CGI server. CGI server loops over the post data and launches perl process for each of the item in the loop. Since requests from clients ends up hitting a single endpoint, I am concerned if I end up creating lots of processes which my server can't handle. Hence I wanted to understand what system metric should I check before launching a new process from loop.

[image]

Note: I have a 20 core machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the answer isn't easy to find, is that it depends on the nature of your processes, and which system constraint is your limiting factor.

For CPU intensive work, then the metric to look at is load average - load average is a measure of processes in a runnable state - very roughly if LA is the same as number of cores, then you're running your CPUs at maximum.

However, it's increasingly the case that CPU is not the limiting factor - you may have a finite amount of memory, and memory hungry processes will consume it. 'spare' memory is used for caching, so filling the whole lot up actually starts to slow things down (because you have a smaller cache). Over spilling the available will either cause swapping or OOMkiller.

But as you mention apache and web, then chances are pretty good that your network pipe is a limiting factor - controlling bandwidth from the local host is actually surprisingly hard.

And then there's disk IO - which may also be a factor - I think that's unlikely for a web server, because your outbound network will usually be a tighter limit.

It all depends what your processes are doing - if they're lightweight 'helpers' that are mostly idle, or heavyweight 'grinders' that all introduce noticeable load.

So the best answer I can give is a very vague estimate - if your processes are CPU intensive, cap them at 2 per core. If your processes are memory, aim to consume about 50% of your system RAM. If your processes are IO intensive, aim to consume about 50% of your IO (either network or disk).